# Do we need to include \ in front of underscores within \cite{}?

Tags: citing, underscore

When underscores are present inside the argument of `\cite{}`, do we need to include `\` in front of the underscores?

e.g.

```
\cite{Plos_One}
```

Comment: no that is simply a key (but you could simply try it, couldn't you?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No -- *unless* you're also loading the [underscore package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/underscore) or have otherwise modified the default properties of the `_` character. (If you've done so, I would assume that you're sufficiently familiar with TeX and LaTeX so as not to have the ask the question in the first place...)

Longer answer: Try to compile the following minimal working example and check whether an error or warning message is generated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{Plos_One}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Plos_One} AAA, BBB, CCC.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not if the `underscore` package has been loaded.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I've updated the first paragraph of my answer to mention this contingency.

Comment: Ok many thanks @Mico. Noob question, what is the code used to load the underscore package?

Comment: @Leockl - `\usepackage{underscore}`.

Comment: Great thanks @Mico