# Can we have a blank line while inside math mode using $$

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I am trying to debug a warning message in my LaTex document. The error message that I am getting is `Missing $ inserted.`

I wanted to check whether can we have a blank line while inside math mode using $$? For eg,

```
$$
R=\{(\rho_1,\Prob_1),(\rho_2,\Prob_2)\}
$$
```

Or should it really be

```
$$ R=\{(\rho_1,\Prob_1),(\rho_2,\Prob_2)\} $$
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see a blank line in the first code example you provide. (`$$` on a line by itself is *not* a blank line.) That said, your code snippet doesn't compile unless one defines `\Prob` suitably.

Comment: Ok thanks @Mico

Comment: You don't say whether you are quoting the error message from the log file or the screen.  You get a lot more information from the log file.  It should give much more context that should allow you to locate the error in the source.

Comment: Hi @barbarabeeton. The error is in the log file. The document I have is a research paper written by a colleague of mine and I am reviewing it. So there are many equations/inputs prior to this displayed math equation. I am trying to debug this warning message and I'm having difficulty in finding out what's wrong. I have checked and all the math symbols/equations appears to be all properly in math mode. Do you know of a way how I can make Latex tell me exactly where this error is? The warning message only says the $ is inserted at the very end of the document just prior to \end{document}

Comment: Hi @Mico. Yeah `\Prob` is loaded properly as a package. The document still compiles properly, but I am just getting this warning message `Missing $ inserted`. I can't figure out whats wrong. I guess if I can't figure out what's wrong, I will just have to leave it be because this message is more of a warning (rather than an an error) and this warning message actually added the missing `$` for me.

Comment: Do please find out how `\Prob` is defined.

Comment: One approach is "divide and conquer".  In a copy of the file, insert `\end{document}` earlier, just not in the middle of math or between a `\begin...\end` pair.  By moving this around, you should be able to localize the problem.  However, I don't think I've ever seen the `Missing $` message without an associated line number.

Comment: @Leockl `Missing $ inserted` is always an error, not a warning and you should fix it. But if the document looks mostly right and the warning is just before `\end{document}`, then the cause of the issue will almost certainly also be in that area. The typical candidate would be some special characters in your bibliography.

Comment: @Mico - it's the package `\newcommand{\Prob}{{\rm p}}`

Comment: Sorry, but that's a *really poor* definition of a math operator. Delete that instruction, make sure the `amsmath` package is loaded, and write `\DeclareMathOperator{\Prob}{p}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, @MarcelKrüger - The associated line number is exactly one line before `\end{document}`. Yeah, I also suspect it;s likely the bib file. I have already checked the bib file and appears fine, though not as extensively as checking the main document file. I will need to have a look at the bib file again. And yeah I will also try to "divide and conquer"

Comment: @Mico -- Regardless of the definition of `\Prob`, it occurs twice in the input, so if it held a spurious `$`, there would be two error messages.  (I'm still voting to check the log file more carefully for a line number.)

Comment: Ah.  One line before `\end{document}`. Then the bibliography is a good bet.  Is there a url in a bib entry, and if so, does it contain an underscore (`_`)?  (This is more easily found in the source than in the output.)  That'll do you in!  Fix it either by preceding the underscore by a backslash (looks not great, but should work), or code the url as `\url{...}` and put `\usepackage{url}` in the preamble.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Yeah there are url's which contains `_`'s in my bib file. I have loaded `\usepackage{url}` in the preamble in my main document file. In my bib file, say I have an url entry which looks like this: `url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-74971-6_16}`. Then, do I need to change this to: `url = \url{https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-74971-6_16}`?

Comment: You would need braces around that: `url = {\url{https:....}}`.

Comment: @WillieWong, @barbarabeeton - Thanks Willie! I have now updated the url's to what you have suggested but I am still getting the error. Can I ask if any of you two know for doi's which contains `_` like this: `doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-74971-6_16}`, do I need to also change anything?

Comment: Ugh.  It appears that whatever bib processor you're using doesn't add the `\url`.  That's not good. if you have a `.bbl` file, that's where it needs to be added, but then the bib processor can't be rerun, or it will destroy what you've just done.  For anything else, more information would be needed, but I'm not a real expert on either bibtex or biblatex processors to be able to fix that easily.

Comment: Since adding the `\url` in the bib file for the url worked, doing the same thing for the doi should also work.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - You mean I can try like this: `doi = {\url{10.1007/978-3-319-74971-6_16}}` to see if it fixes the error?

Comment: Yes, the doi is also intended as a web link, so its format is the same as that of the url.

Comment: Ok many thanks @barbarabeeton. Sorry just one more question. In the bib file, say the first line of a particular reference looks like this: `@article{Wouk_1966,`, which contains an `_`. Do I need to change it to add the backslash like this: `@article{Wouk\_1966,`? I know that in my main document file when I use `\cite{}` to cite this paper/reference, I don't need to use the backslash before the `_` inside `\cite{}`

Comment: Didn't you already ask the latest question, in [Do we need to include \ in front of underscores within \cite{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/588567/5001)? The answer hasn't changed in the meantime.

Comment: Hi @Mico, yeah I did. But that was for `\cite{}` used in the main document file. Now, in the bib file, say I have the first line of a particular reference which looks like this: `@article{Wouk_1966,`, which contains `_`. So does this work in the bib file too (ie. without having to add the backslash before the `_`) or do I need to add the backslash for the first line of a reference in the bib file which contains `_`?

Comment: Because using `_` in the argument of `\cite` is ok, and because the argument of `\cite` is the "key" to a bibliographic entry, it follows that it *must* be ok to use `_` in the key.

Comment: Ok many thanks @Mico!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) You should not use `$$` in LaTeX. Use `\[`...`\]` or `\begin{displaymath}`...`\end{displaymath}` instead.

(2) new lines are not a problem in math mode.

(iii) blank lines (e.g., what you use to mark paragraphs) are very much a problem but you don't show this in your samples

(****) Most likely the problem is something in the input before this displayed math equation, or else in the definition of `\Prob` so we don't have enough information to identify the source of your difficulty.

Comment: Ok thanks! The document I have is a research paper written by a colleague of mine and I am reviewing it. So there are many equations/inputs prior to this displayed math equation. I am trying to debug this warning message and I'm having difficulty in finding out what's wrong. All the math symbols/equations are all properly in math mode. Do you know of a way how I can make Latex let me know exactly where this error is? The warning message only says the `$` is inserted at the very end of the document just prior to `\end{document}`

Comment: Because blank lines aren't allowed in math mode, it's almost certainly in the last paragraph of the document, assuming you aren't ignoring other errors earlier in the file.